# Django-cms placeholder in cms template breaks page

Tags: python, django, templates, content-management-system, django-cms

So I moved my cms templates to a /cms folder in the templates folder:

**templates/cms/default_template.html**

I edited the settings.py as follows:

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('cms/default_template.html', 'Default Template'),
)
```

My template looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block base_content %}
    {% placeholder template_1_content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Problem is it throws the following error on page load:

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /en/**

**Error during template rendering**

```
3   
4   {% block base_content %}
5   ***{% placeholder template_1_content %}*** -> This line is red indicating the problem is here
6   {% endblock %}
```

If I remove the {% placeholder template_1_content %} the page loads fine no problems.
It's only after adding that placeholder that it goes bonkers for no reason I can think of.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

BTW the page will load with the placeholder if I don't use the /cms folder.
So what is it about the placeholder and the folder location???

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Turns out the name of the first template created was stored in the database and that was being referenced. I had to manually edit the database to the new location and name of the template